# How to add rating bar in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

here Im getting list of data to which Im assigning it to a listview... In that i need to display user ratings to every Item.. So when the user rating is $.. I need to display 4stars in greeen color and another 1 star in gray color.. Im unable to do this.. Can anyone please tell me

```
 <ListView ItemSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White"  Padding="5" >
          <Grid Padding="3"     BackgroundColor="White" >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ffimageloading:CachedImage HeightRequest="100" Aspect="AspectFill"

              LoadingPlaceholder="image_loading.png" ErrorPlaceholder="image_error.png"
              Source="{Binding Images}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <!--<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
          <Label x:Name="Label" 
       Text="{Binding FileName}" />
          <Label Text="uhfuiehuegirtj"/>
          <Label Text="ufoidjgoidrjiojkgorij"/>
        </StackLayout>-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Text="{Binding CourseName}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding CourseDescription}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="graystar.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" x:Name="Img1"/>
                <Image Source="graystar.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" x:Name="Img2"/>
                <Image Source="graystar.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" x:Name="Img3"/>
                <Image Source="graystar.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" x:Name="Img4"/>
                <Image Source="graystar.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" x:Name="Img5"/>

              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding CoursePrice}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Image="wishlist.png" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="btn_clicked"/>
              </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Frame>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of samples and controls out there. You don't really need to do it yourself. Syncfusion offers some nice controls for Xamarin. There is a free Community License too.

I think that's what you want -> https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin